# an integer array pointing to an array of integers?

Tags: c, pointers

I am now studying CMU 15-213. 
Here's the code that confuses me:

```
#define ZLEN 5
typedef int zipdig[ZLEN] ;
#define UCOUNT 3

zipdig cmu = {1, 5, 2, 1, 3};
zipdig mit = {0, 2, 1, 3, 9};
zipdig ucb = {9, 4, 7, 2, 0};

int *univ[UCOUNT] = {mit, cmu, ucb};
```

I am a little confused about the last sentence, because I regard univ as an array of 3 integer pointers, so how can it point to integer array? For example, if I dereference the element in univ, should the result be an integer or an integer array? (I guess it should be an integer)

Comment: See the duplicate. `mit`, `cou` and `ucb` decay to `int*`. Note that your syntax looks wrong.

Comment: yes I have corrected it.

Comment: You are right. That is an array of pointers to `int`, not to "array of `int`". Congratulations, you encountered one of the most confusing subjects in the C language! And did ask the right question.

Comment: thanks. And now I am trying to figure out how to represent a pointer pointing to an array of ints.